# Downloaded music/video can't be seen on Lumia 532

Tags: lumia, storage, downloads

How to find downloaded songs or videos in my phone, Lumia 532? The downloads folder is empty.

Comment: From which application you've downloaded music/video ??

Comment: Which application or browser did you use to download the media files..?

Comment: Please complete the question. Did you mean downloads location from any browser or any specific app? Are you on 8.1 or 10?

Answer (score 1):

I was already answer on the same question. Go to setting, then storage and check where it is saved. [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl) is the Microsoft App so here you can find all your files and documents

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Microsoft store and download the [Files](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL) app. This is a file manager application that you can use to browse through the files on both your phone, and your Micro SD card.

After that, open the application, and browse into your default save location for downloads. Usually, if you used your browser to do the downloads, you should find a `Downloads` folder in either your Phone or SD Card storage locations.

[image]

If you cannot find the folders, then try searching for the filename or keyword of ***one of*** the songs you downloaded. If you find one, long press on it and click on "`Browse to item`". This will take you to the location on which the said downloads you made.

[image]